# In Minishift, Web Console API path not changed to public domain setting

Tags: networking, openshift, web-console, minishift

My case would be, I would like to share my minishift instance to my intranet network.

It looks like there is no option to choose the network / IP, e.g. if you try to set the virtualbox network interface to "bridge", it would just fail

So I would like to setup port forwarding, e.g. http://blog.brianjohn.com/forwarding-ports-in-os-x-el-capitan.html

In this case I am able to access to the web console, e.g. redirect port of machine IP:PORT to 192.168.64.4:8443 (minishift)

But all the API, e.g. "https://192.168.64.4:8443/api/v1" are still using the internal IP, which of course it can not be accessed externally.

Are there any way to make it work properly?

Answer (score 1):

When I need to access minishift from other hosts, I use SSH tunneling. 
First you need to enable SSH access in your OSX and make sure you enable `AllowTcpForwarding`. Then create another user in your laptop to login via SSH.

From other hosts you need to login using SSH with following command:

```
ssh -L 8443:192.168.64.4:8443 user@<you_laptop_IP_address>
```

Keep the user logged in so that you can access your minishift web console using browser to `https://localhost:8443`